# Why instance attribute created by merging other attribute doesn't change,even when original attribute gets override

Tags: python

I am not able to comprehend why the self.details is printing the same line even after changing the object attribute self.name and self.author.

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.details = self.name + ' written by ' + self.author

bk = Book("Harry Potter", "J K Rowling")
print(bk.name)
print(bk.author)
print(bk.details)   #Harry Potter written by J K Rowling

bk.name = 'Becoming'
bk.marks= 'Michelle Obama'
print(bk.name)
print(bk.author)
print(bk.details)   #Harry Potter written by J K Rowling
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `details` is created from the original values. After the concatenation occurs, it's entirely independent of the other values. If you want a dynamically constructed string using the current values of `name`/`author`, [use a `property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to compute `details` dynamically on access (without storing it as an attribute at all):

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        # Don't make a `details` attribute at all

    @property
    def details(self):
        # This method is called whenever you refer to `somebook.details`
        return self.name + ' written by ' + self.author
```

Comment: why it is independent of other values,that's what i am not able to understand.as far as property is concerned,i agree on that.

Comment: @d.m: What happens when you do `x = 1`, `y = 2`, `z = x + y`, `x = 3`? Hint: `z` is not `5`. That's just how programming languages work; it's not useful to have the default behavior be a permanent, dynamic tie between operands and the result. Instance attributes aren't any different from plain variables, because if they were, it would be *very* surprising in a lot of cases.

Comment: i understand x=3 would not set z=5,but z=x+y followed by x=3 would definitely will make 5.Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @d.m: Your understanding is wrong. `z = x + y` means "Set `z` equal to the sum of the *current* values of `x` and `y`". It's not a permanent association with either `x` or `y`. If you wanted `z` to be `5`, you'd need to set `z = x + y` again, *after* setting `x` to `3`.

Answer (score 3):

`self.details` is created and set once when doing `self.details = self.name + ' written by ' + self.author` but it isn't linked to it. The `+` operation just does a concatenation of strings.

Exactly, with your first example, Python reads `self.details = self.name + ' written by ' + self.author` so it does `self.details = "Harry Potter" + ' written by ' + "J K Rowling"` and so `self.details = "Harry Potter written by J K Rowling"`

It is just an attribute with a string as its value. This string will stay immutable until you change it explicitly.

If you want this behaviour, you may look into getter and setter, and make a setter for `self.name` and `self.author` automatically updating `self.details`